# Broadcast data to multiple widgets in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, broadcastreceiver, nsnotificationcenter, flutter

Is there a way to broadcast data from one widget to other widgets? Similar to a BroadcastReceiver on Android or NSNotificationCenter on iOS.

Specifically, I'm trying to detect when a Navigator pops or pushes a new view. I added navigatorObservers to MaterialApp. And when a widget comes back to the foreground, I want to be able to notify it by broadcasting changes from didPush and didPop with the actual route that's in the current foreground

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, but could you explain *why* you want to be notified of these changes? What are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: Perhaps it's done differently on Flutter, but basically, in my case, when a user sees a login page, he presses the login button and goes through the login flow. Once done, I close the login flow and expose the login page. If we now have valid access tokens, I close the login page and replace it with the content page. Normally, I would have done this in onResume or onActivityResult in Android. But I can't find something similar to that on Flutter. The only thing I could think of is to detect when the Navigator pops or pushes view and see which view route is in the foreground.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Navigator.push` returns a `Future` that will complete when `Navigator.pop` is called (and this can optionally be used to pass data back to the widget that called `push`). So for example suppose your login button has this `onPressed` handler:

```
onPressed: () async {
  bool isLoggedIn = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

When your login page calls `Navigator.pop(true)`, the `Future` will complete with a value of `true` which will be assigned to the `isLoggedIn` variable. (You'll get `null` if the user uses the back button to return to the previous screen.)

This is how `showDialog` works as well.

Comment: Ahhh interesting. I didn't consider that. Thank you!!

Comment: This can also be achieved by `Navigator.pop(context, true)` for a closed dialog to return true.

Comment: Not reaching if block