# Flutter - How the NavigatorObserver class works?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to detect when the **navigator** performs the basic operations (**push** and **pop**), I found that the class to achieve this is with the [NavigatorObserver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html) class, but I can't find an example on how it works.

I already tried implements the interface:

```
class MyClassState extends State<MyClass> with NavigatorObserver{

    ....

    @override
    void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
        print('This is never get called');
    }

    @override
    void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
        print('This is never get called');
    }
}
```

Of course I'm calling `Navigator.of(context).push(...);`
But the override methods, never get called.

I suspect the binding with the navigator is missing, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I think what I want to do is very simple but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a **page A** that pushes **page B**.

On **page B** I have a **periodic timer** that **must** be on there (on **page B**).

All what I want to do is to cancel the timer with `timer.cancel()` when the **page B** get popped out (with back button on Android or back button in appbar), since when the **page B** get popped out the timer still executing even if the **page B** has gone.

- I can't pass the timer as param with the Navigator.pop() since I don't handle the back buttons (the one in the appbar and the Android back button).

**EDIT 2:**

-I found a way that solves the problem, what I did was cancel the timer on the

```
@override
void dispose() {
  timer.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

method. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish it.

**NOTE:**

With this workaround the timer still executing if I press the Home button or open the multitask on Android, and when go back to the app this are restarted but again the timer still executing its code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the time you don't need to implement `NavigatorObserver`. See [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44417260/1463116) explaining how to use `push` and `pop` to pass information between routes. In the use case you've described, you should `addListener` to an `AnimationController`, using the [`TickerProviderStateMixin`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TickerProviderStateMixin-class.html) to obtain a suitable `vsync` object. This ensures that your callback will not fire when the app is suspended or after your `State` is disposed. (Instead of `addListener`, you could use an `AnimatedBuilder` or `AnimatedWidget` the primary purpose of your callback is to rebuild a section of the widget tree.)

The main time when you'd want a `NavigatorObserver` is if you're using a plugin like Firebase Analytics. You can see an example usage in the [plugins repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/lib/main.dart#L34). You pass the `NavigatorObserver` in the `navigatorObservers` argument to the `MaterialApp` constructor:

```
static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
  new FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);
...
return new MaterialApp(
  navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
  ...
);
```

It is unusual to have a `State` that implements `NavigatorObserver` because your `MaterialApp` should be near the top of the widget hierarchy. At the time you're constructing it, most `State` objects won't exist yet so you'll have a hard time putting them into the `navigatorObservers` array. You might instead use a class that isn't a `State`. If necessary, you can use `GlobalKey<MyClassState>` to find the `State` that needs to be notified (but if you're doing this, there might be an easier way to accomplish what you want).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I have edited the question with the main problem that I want to solve, please check it, I don't know if I'm using the easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: Aha, you are trying to solve a problem that definitely doesn't need `NavigatorObserver`. I edited my answer with some advice about using `AnimationController` instead of firing a timer.

Comment: Ok, I got the point, using an AnimationController should be work perfectly, but, Is there a way to execute the callback of the AnimationController periodically? As the Timer.perdiodic did?

Comment: You can just call `repeat()` on the `AnimationController` to get it to restart automatically, or you can `forward(from: 0.0)` on the `AnimationController` when it finishes.

Comment: Using the `AnimationController` with `forward(from: 0.0)` solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13):

```
// Register the RouteObserver as a navigation observer.
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
  ));
}

class RouteAwareWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<RouteAwareWidget> createState() => RouteAwareWidgetState();
}

// Implement RouteAware in a widget's state and subscribe it to the RouteObserver.
class RouteAwareWidgetState extends State<RouteAwareWidget> with RouteAware {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // Route was pushed onto navigator and is now topmost route.
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Covering route was popped off the navigator.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();

}
```

This is a more detailed help guide.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea

Comment: It might be more helpful to the OP to explain why this is a good alternative to the answer already provided and accepted. It might be obvious to you, but it won't be obvious to other readers.

Comment: would you put this code on every page you want to watch? if so what if I wanted to watch all the pages in my application to run a function on change

Comment: @Ares? I want to know this too.

Comment: This is simple copy-paste from Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html#widgets.RouteObserver.1). Where is the explanation?

Comment: Please have a look at the link I have attached.

Comment: All these examples show all the code in a single "file", how would you access the routeObserver from a screen declared in another file.

Comment: To access routeObserver is enough to import the main file. But in the method didChangeDependencies, how do you have visibility over BuildContext context? This code is almost everywhere and I am still facing the lack of visibility over context: "Error: The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'"

Comment: `didChangeDependencies` can be called multiple times between mount and unmount -- you should set a flag when `routeObserver.subscribe` has been called, and only ever subscribe once.