# Get the previous route name in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigator

I understand that Flutter routes works like a stack, so I want to know the previous route name which I came from.

I'm using a `preview page` to show a picture, but this picture can come from the camera or the gallery, I'd like to show a dialog only if it came from gallery.

I read I have to use an observer, but I think there is an easy way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no built-in mechanism for that, you have to use `NavigatorObserver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) pack to get previous Route

```
Get.previousRoute;
```

get current Route

```
Get.currentRoute;
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best way to do it and the most accurate answer.

Comment: This has a bug with dialog. Is there any way that can get these routes without the context? The `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name` not work with `Get.context!`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, upon further investigation, there is no way to know the previous page.

I fixed this sending an argument `previousPage` with the route name value.

You can also use a `NavigatorObserver`.

Comment: Can you give example how `NavigatorObserver` can retrieve previous route name ?

Comment: `MaterialApp` has an attr called navigatorObservers. You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165705/flutter-how-the-navigatorobserver-class-works