# Display custom Flutter widget similar to SnackBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to display a widget on the then-current screen when some asynchronous data comes in. However, I don't want it to be a SnackBar or a MaterialBanner, but rather my own widget with my own look and feel.

The issue is that I haven't been able to figure out how to determine which "screen"/route is current; i.e. which State to update. I've looked at Scaffold.of, RouteObserver, provider, and a few other things, but haven't been able to get anything to work.

I've also looked at ScaffoldMessenger but haven't figured out how to make it display anything besides a SnackBar or MaterialBanner. (I know that both SnackBar and MaterialBanner are somewhat customizable but that's not what I'm looking for.)

To simplify a bit, what I need is the `xxxxx` below:

```
    static void gotData(Object data) {
      Widget msgbox = messageBox(data); // similar to SnackBar. a message widget.
      globalstuff.msgbox = msgbox;      // my routes will position/display this in each build()
      xxxxx.setState(() {});            // how do i get xxxxx?
    }
```

This might seem basic/silly but I just haven't been able to make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overlay to display your own customized widget instead of the default Snackbar.

Here's a code snippet for that :

```
Future<void> showCustomNotification({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Widget child,
}) async {
  OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
  OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
    builder: (c) {
      return Positioned(
        bottom: 16,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
  overlayState?.insert(overlayEntry);
  overlayState?.setState(() {});
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500));
  overlayEntry.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work well when passed the context from the current route, but I get an exception if I trigger it with a delay, and change routes before the overlay appears. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try passing in the `context` of the parent of both the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use RouteObserver to keep track of the current route, using information from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206693/936098

Armed with the current route and the ability to call `setState()` on it, all that remained was to modify my various routes' `build()` methods to display a popup with the async information when appropriate.