# How to handle onPause/onResume in Flutter App?

Tags: android, timer, dart, flutter, ticker

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and would like to build a simple app where a LinearProgressBar gets updated every second.

Without getting too much into the actual code, I have the following setup working.

- A function that calculates the progress, based on passed time.
- A LinearProgressBar showing the progress.
- A periodic Timer recalculating the progress and updating the progress bar every second.
- I debugprint 'tick' every time, the recalculation is done.

Everything is working as expected with one exception. The 'tick' keeps getting printed when I move the app in the background on my Android device.

On native Android, I would cancel my periodic Timer when the 'onPause' event is triggered.

Is there something similar in Flutter? All I could find was 'initState' and 'dispose'. Dispose, however, does not get called when moving the app to background.

I don't want the timer to keep ticking in the background.

On my research, I found this Stack Overflow question [onresume-and-onpause-for-widgets-on-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331725/onresume-and-onpause-for-widgets-on-flutter). It's answer suggests using [TickerProviderStateMixin](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TickerProviderStateMixin-class.html).

I used it the following way.

```
class _BarItemState extends State<BarItem> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    Ticker ticker;
    num progress = 1.0;

    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();
       ticker = createTicker((duration) => setState(() {
          debugPrint('tick');
          progress = duration.inSeconds / 30;
       }))
      ..start();
    }

    // other stuff omitted

}
```

It is working, but I'm still not satisfied.

The reason is, that the ticker callback is getting now called every few milliseconds instead of once a second. This seems to me like a waste of resources (I don't need a smooth animation), ... am I overcomplicating things?

Even if it seems that I don't need it for my use case, I still would like to know:

How to handle the onPause/onResume events on my own?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can override the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` of the `WidgetBindingObserver` interface to receive notifications for *app lifecycle* changes.

There's sample code in [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504433/5219642 for more detail you can check this

Answer (score 13):

You can use [lifecycle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChannels/lifecycle-constant.html) channel from [SystemChannels](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChannels-class.html).

Example:

```
SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg){
  debugPrint('SystemChannels> $msg');
});
```

Output:

```
I/flutter ( 3672): SystemChannels> AppLifecycleState.paused
I/flutter ( 3672): SystemChannels> AppLifecycleState.resumed
```

Comment: I felt that amirs solution is more idomatic. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: This may be obvious to others, but it took me a while to figure out I needed to move this to a location after the Flutter runApp call.

Answer (score 0):

From Flutter 3.13 onwards we can follow the new approach **AppLifecycleListener** instead of **WidgetBindingObserver**, It has some extra features compared to WidgetBindingObserver

[Dart Pad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=51e41b2b9ddfa466d86890324fae2c31)

Create a stateful class and declare App lifecycle listener property

```
  late final AppLifecycleListener _listener;
```

Create an **AppLifecycleListener** class instance in **initState**, and pass the required callbacks in it as shown below

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    lifeCycleListener = AppLifecycleListener(
      onStateChange: _onLifeCycleChanged
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Dispose the listener

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    lifeCycleListener.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Implement your logic _onLifeCycleChanged based on the lifecycle

```
  void _onLifeCycleChanged(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch(state){
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
    }
  }
```

In **WidgetsBindingObserver** when overriding the didChangeAppLifecycleState method, we can only listen for the actual state change, for example when your app got into the resumed state. In **AppLifecycleListener** we can listen to the transitions between the states, for example, whether your app got into the resumed state from the inactive as shown below.

```
    lifeCycleListener = AppLifecycleListener(
      onStateChange: _onLifeCycleChanged,
      onDetach: _onDetach,
      onPause: _onPause
      ....
    );


   /// on Detach this will be called
  _onDetach() => print('on Detach');
  _onPause() => print('on Pause');
  ....
```

One more feature is **onExitRequested** callback, we can alert the user before closing the application, I think this will be used in desktop based applications

```
  AppLifecycleListener(
      onExitRequested: _onExit
    );

  Future<AppExitResponse> _onExit() async {
    final response = await showDialog<AppExitResponse>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Are you sure you want to close app?'),
        content: const Text('All unsaved date will be lost.'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(AppExitResponse.cancel);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Exist the App'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(AppExitResponse.exit);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return response ?? AppExitResponse.exit;
  }
```