# How to reload a page on Navigation.pop in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I want to have page A reload, re-run the Http requests, once I pop back to it from another page that lets you edit the data page A displays. The other page is triggered by a long press in a ListView generated by a function within page A. IE:
Page A:

_PageAState

- Reload function I need to call

Scaffold

- List item
- Text
- ETC...
- Expanded

  - ListView

    - Gesture Detector that navigates
- ETC

How can I trigger a function of any sort or make the page reload when I pop back to it?

I've tried passing data from the pop and using an if statement but the nested structure messes it up.

Comment: refer to https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/

Comment: I've read this but thanks for the reference. The issue is accessing any of these methods because the new page and page A are both stateful and I can't seem to access methods in the _PageState class.

Comment: possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256443/9823185

Answer (score 1):

of course, there's a way to do that!
As you realized, the first route needs to get notified when the pushed Route gets popped.

Thankfully, there's a [tutorial in the Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) that handles returning data from `Route`s.
In your case, no data gets returned but you can still use the same principle to wait for the route to be popped: Simply `await` the `Navigator.push` call!
This will return once the other route gets popped.

```dart
await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherPage()),
);
// TODO: Now, refetch the data.
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the Navigation is in a different file and class from the data function. I have a ListBuilder and the item's for the ListBuilder in a separate file and class from Page A. I can't seem to access any of the methods declared in _PageAState I'm not sure how I could go about doing that.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well, as far as I know forcing a widget on a different page to update itself doesn't align with how Flutter's rendering works, so my educated guess is this isn't possible.