# flutter - Call State's method when widget reappears in viewport

Tags: dart, flutter

Saying, I have a `SliverList` widget with `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`, which produces a card with custom image widget inside of it for each index. By custom image widget I mean widget that is kind of `NetworkImage`, but with support for custom caching technology. It's similar to [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image).

So, the problem I'm trying to solve is that when some image fails to load and user scrolls it out from the screen, I need to retry loading this image when user for example scrolls back to it or in general when this image appears in viewport again.

Is it possible to e.g. re-call image loading function in some of the State's lifecycle methods or in delegate's builder? Or which technique should I use in this case?

Github issue [#29597](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29597)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069712/how-to-know-if-a-widget-is-visible-within-a-viewport

Comment: @DanielP I’ve already seen this solution. Unfortunately, it’s not memory efficient, and I need such check for every element in scrollview, not only one