# How to track ListView items, to know when they are in the ViewPort in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I'm trying to track which items of ListView are in the ViewPort?

This was the best example I could find, but I'm not sure it I can be made to work with multiple items...

[How to know if a widget is visible within a viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069712/how-to-know-if-a-widget-is-visible-within-a-viewport/51073389)

Any advice would be appreciated! I will keep working though!