# How to add a view counter in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, view, counter

I'd like you to guide me on how I can detect if a user has seen an item so implement a view counter

as on the image below

[image: An exemple of view counter]

Is there any widget I need to use to get this result? What searches do I need to do to get this result?

Comment: These kind of things stored at backend but if you want to store it on your device, you can use local DB like sqflite and in "init state" method of the page, increment the count of the views in the DB.

Comment: Yes I know, I store this data in the back-end, what I see is to know how to detect when the user sees the computer and then increment my counter.

Comment: Didn't get which computer you're talking about? You can check if the page completely loads then you can increment the counter.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... EDIT Yes I know, I store this data in the back-end, what I see is to know how to detect when the user sees the post or article and then increment my counter

Comment: If you want to get this behavior on scrolling the list then you can get help from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069712/how-to-know-if-a-widget-is-visible-within-a-viewport/57252652#57252652 and if you want to get it on the separate screen then you can follow the above mentioned approach.

Comment: Thanks you a lot