# Check if a widget is visible

Tags: flutter

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` that contains some widgets inside it. I want to listen if a widget becomes visible on the screen. is there any widget or sample code for this scenario?

Comment: Try these answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069712/how-to-know-if-a-widget-is-visible-within-a-viewport) someone asked the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One package might be helpful is [VisibilityDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector). You should be able to wrap around your child widget like this and execute callbacks

```
VisibilityDetector(
key: Key('my-widget-key'),
onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
  var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
  debugPrint(
      'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
},
child: someOtherWidget,
);
```