# how to Know which screen is on the top(active/mounted)

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

iam implementing app with Flutter that has a pin screen must be entered to access the app, pin shows every time you resume the app so iam using ([didChangeAppLifecycleState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571863/8623062)) the problem here that if something interups the app like whatsapp notification the pin shows and thats cool ,, but if two messages comes , i get two pin codes and so one , once i got 27 pin codes i have to enter them to resume the app and that's not cool at all

so the question here , is there any method or way to know which screen is on the top of stack(Navigator Stack) ? i mean visible to the user right now, so i don't have to show pin again ,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have 3 pages in your App, namely 'PageHome', 'Page1', 'PagePin'.  Then:

1. create a file 'GlobalVariables.dart', inside this file, create a class gv.
2. Inside class gv, create a static var:

   ```
   static String strCurPage = 'PageHome';
   ```
3. Import this dart file in all 3 pages.
4. Before navigate to a new page, e.g. from 'PageHome' to 'PagePin', set:

   ```
   gv.strCurPage = 'PagePin';
   ```
5. When the app resume from background, navigate to 'PagePin' only if gv.strCurPage != 'PagePin'.